# Manually changing coordinates of anchor point before rotation in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, vector-grid, anchor-point

I am working with a fishnet of over 120,000 elements, so any editing or selection operation is inevitably lengthy.

I need to rotate this fishnet by an angle of 17 degrees anti-clockwise, but as soon as I put the fishnet shapefile in editing mode (and after having waited for quite a while), the anchor point is visualized in a location that is not the one I want. If I kept it there, the rotation would give me a wrong result. Every time I try to select the anchor and move it with my cursor, ArcGIS gets stuck (perhaps it is selecting all the squares in the fishnet once again) and *I am not able to move the anchor to the desired position*.

Is there a way to manually change the coordinates of the anchor point?

I would also be open to a Python/ArcPy solution to this.

Comment: Why rotate a fishnet manually when you can create a new one with the correct rotation so easily?

Comment: No, it is not so easy to rotate the fishnet when you create it. I have tried all possible combinations of coordinates I have but to no avail. The fishnet is always created non-rotated. ESRI should have made this easier.

Comment: Look at the documentation on fishnet creation. The second parameter (Y axis) lets you rotate by specifying a location not directly north of the origin.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) duplicate of [How to make fishnet grid with specified rotation angle in ArcGIS for Desktop?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114713/how-to-make-fishnet-grid-with-specified-rotation-angle-in-arcgis-for-desktop)

Comment: @Vince this is not a possible duplicate as my question relates to how to change the anchor coordinates. And for the documentation, it is not at all self-explaining.

Comment: I doubt your solution can be made workable, but your root problem is already solved. A web search on "arcgis fishnet" will turn up dozens of guides which will agree that it's confusing (even one within the documentation itself), but a tool that powerful isn't easy to make simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in Edit mode in ArcMap you can manually change the anchor point.

Select your features to display the anchor point.

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move your mouse pointer over the anchor point - you will see the pointer change to a four-way arrow.

[image]

You can now select the anchor point and move it to your desired position.  This makes use of snapping also, so if you have your snapping environment set correctly you can have it snap to a vertex or edge as required to get an exact position.

[image]

Your anchor point is now where you want it, and you can now rotate your fishnet as required.  Can also be used if you want to move your features to snap to an edge/vertex of another feature (this is the main thing I use this for)

[image]