# ArcGIS: fishnet with rotation angle and coordinates error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid, angles, arcgis-10.5

I have a micro plots map shapefile with NDVI data. I want to create a fishnet of polygons to divide the map into the micro plots. I have being able to create a fishnet with polygons but I cannot place it on top of my map.

[image]

I know my map has a -32 angle rotation. I have tried to modify the coordinates but still get the wrong placement for fishnet as you can see in the image.

I am now using ArcMap 10.5

Comment: Put an example or picture

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114713/creating-fishnet-grid-with-specified-rotation-angle-in-arcgis-desktop