# Split a vector into parallel grids

Tags: qgis, vector, grids-graticules, field-mapping

I have a piece of land (vector) with, for example, potatoes and I want to make a grid for spraying. That means i need a grid with size 45mx10m with different values per box. Important is that the grid is parallel to one boundary of the vector. With Vector Grid the grid is always facing north. Could anyone help me?

---

[image]

Imagine this is the field. The grid should be parallel to the left boundary of the field. The size of the boxes should be the same size, exactly. Except the right side of course.

Comment: Could you draw how would it look like?

Comment: In QGIS, you can make a Vector Grid, then Rotate and Move it manually.

Comment: Are you actually after the how to plan the optimal route

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ArcGIS, the Create Fishnet tool allows you to set an origin for the fishnet and then give the coordinates of a point which the Y-axis will pass through to specify your desired angle.

@Chris W provides a good explanation here: [Creating fishnet grid with specified rotation angle in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114713/creating-fishnet-grid-with-specified-rotation-angle-in-arcgis-desktop)