# Building fishnet using polygon feature class as center of fishnet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I'm interested in creating a fishnet where the origin of the fishnet builds from the center of a polygon feature class and builds out around it rather than building the fishnet starting from the lower left corner and only only the Y-axis and X-axis as depicted below. Using, ArcGIS, arcpy, python etc... is doable.

I've tried a variety of approaches, attempting to change the origin, at least think I was able to, or adding some sort of value to "buffer" or "pad" the input extent and or xy values, to no avail. I haven't come across much that can offer me in assistance thus far.

[Creating fishnet grid with specified rotation angle in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114713/creating-fishnet-grid-with-specified-rotation-angle-in-arcgis-desktop) includes a response:

> However, if you don't want to do the math or need to set your origin at a different point than the CRS origin, there's a step to take prior to starting the fishnet tool to get your y-axis coordinate.

However, I'm not sure how to implement.

I've read through:

- [Create Fishnet](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-fishnet.htm)
- [How Create Fishnet works](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want the center of the Fishnet at the center of the polygon, calculate the polygon extent, offset the origin half the extent.

Comment: Would you like cell size of fixed dimensions?

Comment: @FelixIP, yes I would.

Comment: @klewis I just tried that, the tool fails to produce a result, could you show an example or provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanical solution. Create fishnet using your dimensions:

[image]

Use half of the line between two points as displacement link in spatial adjustment toolbar to get this:

[image]

Alternatively use half of the line connecting upper right corners:

[image]

to get:

[image]

Easy to code.